# How to have a partial grayscale image using Python Pillow (PIL)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Example:

[image: partial grayscale]

- 1st image: the original image.
- 2nd, 3rd and 4th images: the outputs I
  want.

I know PIL has the method `PIL.ImageOps.grayscale(image)` that returns the 4th image, but it doesn't have parameters to produce the 2nd and 3rd ones (partial grayscale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import ImageEnhance
# value: float between 0.0 (grayscale) and 1.0 (original)
ImageEnhance.Color(image).enhance(value)
```

P.S.: Mark's solution works, but it seems to be increasing the exposure.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert an image to greyscale, you are essentially desaturating it to remove saturated colours. So, in order to achieve your desired effect, you probably want to convert to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) mode, reduce the saturation and convert back to RGB mode.

```
from PIL import Image

# Open input image
im = Image.open('potato.png')

# Convert to HSV mode and separate the channels
H, S, V = im.convert('HSV').split()

# Halve the saturation - you might consider 2/3 and 1/3 saturation
S = S.point(lambda p: p//2)

# Recombine channels
HSV = Image.merge('HSV', (H,S,V))

# Convert to RGB and save
result = HSV.convert('RGB')
result.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you prefer to do your image processing in Numpy rather than PIL, you can achieve the same result as above with this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open input image
im = Image.open('potato.png')

# Convert to HSV and go to Numpy
HSV = np.array(im.convert('HSV'))

# Halve the saturation with Numpy. Hue will be channel 0, Saturation is channel 1, Value is channel 2
HSV[..., 1] = HSV[..., 1] // 2

# Go back to "PIL Image", go back to RGB and save
Image.fromarray(HSV, mode="HSV").convert('RGB').save('result.png')
```

---

Of course, set the entire Saturation channel to zero for full greyscale.